# Loading Denormalized Data into a Datawarehouse

Tags: normalization, data-modeling, data-warehouse

We are building a data warehouse by consuming file feeds from different sources.
The file feeds are all denormalized/flattened (In the Transactions (fact) file, the Account attributes keeps repeating in all the records).

Also, the account information changes often (the feed gives an as-is version of the data).

What is the best practice in this situation.  Should the data warehouse have a star schema model (with the Account information as a slowly changing dimension and a Transaction fact).  Will re-normalizing make the ETL process complex?

Answer (score 2):

In my company, whenever some input is denormalized, we normalize it and from there we proceed with loading our schemas (whatever your schema is).

The reason is that, being de-normalized, those inputs are difficult to check for  inconsistencies (data quality). Apart from that, conforming all of your inputs to some standard allows your code to be more maintainable.

In our case, following the Kimball practices has been a total success, fact table, slow changing dimensions and all that jazz.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without such details as daily volume, latency threshold, resource availability, reporting requirements, platform and tool constraints, etc.  A traditional ODS, where you import into and store a normalized structure before creating data marts from that, is great but not optimal for big data or real time analysis.  A more modern approach, using a data lake in Hadoop or a virtualization layer, may not be feasible for your organization.

General Opinions:

1) re-normalizing does seem unnecessary from both a complexity and performance standpoint unless you have some ongoing use for the normalized data store.

2) Whether or not you build a traditional star schema or a graph or whatever should be governed by the reporting requirements and tools, not the source data format.  Those sources will change, btw.

3) "Transaction" does not sound like a fact to me.  A purchase transaction, e.g., could feed a sales fact, an accumulating snapshot for a sales cycle, a funnel conversion fact, etc.

4) I'm not sure whether "Account" is a customer, or a balance account such as a credit card, online payment service, bank account, etc.  They imply different SCD types.  In any case, Google will be sufficient to get plenty of information about building those dimensions.